# boost::any type change leading to illegal access

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr

While testing the examples trough the boost cpp libraries book I noticed that changing the type stored inside a boost::any variable may lead to an illegal access instead of an exception:

good:

```
boost::any a = 1;
bool *p = boost::any_cast<bool>(&a); // ok, bad cast exception
```

bad:

```
boost::any a = std::string { "Boost" };
a = 1;
bool *p = boost::any_cast<bool>(&a); // no exception thrown
std::cout << std::boolalpha << *p << '\n'; // illegal access
```

My question therefore is: is this a bug as it seems or is it some underlying fact related to templates usage that I am not aware of?

Comment: "Doctor, it hurts when I move my arm this way." ... "Well, don't move your arm that way."

Comment: `v=boost::any a = 1; bool *p = boost::any_cast<bool>(&a); // ok, bad cast exception` what?  No, that does not happen.

Comment: Thank you, you are right, also as Ami Tavory pointed out I was looking at the wrong code section. Since however his explanation is sound I have updated the code in the question.

Comment: @AlexC I would recommend to rather keep the question as it is, to avoid confusion.

Comment: @SauravSahu - done, hope this doesn't actually shift the focus from the real issue in the code, which is pointed out by Ami

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I understand [the documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/boost/any_cast.html) differently:

> **Returns:** If passed a pointer, it returns a similarly qualified pointer to the value content if successful, otherwise null is returned. If T is ValueType, it returns a copy of the held value, otherwise, if T is a reference to (possibly const qualified) ValueType, it returns a reference to the held value.
>
> **Throws:** Overloads taking an *any* pointer do not throw; overloads taking an *any* value or reference throws *bad_any_cast* if unsuccessful.

So:

1. The success or failure of the conversion depends on the stored type and target type.
2. The manifestation of failure though, depends on whether you pass a pointer to `any_cast` or not. If you pass a pointer, the manifestation is a `nullptr`; otherwise, the manifestation is an exception.

Consider for example this code:

```
#include <boost/any.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    boost::any a = 1;
```

This seems to contradict the statement in your question - since it takes a pointer, it doesn't throw, but the pointer is `nullptr`:

```
    bool *p = boost::any_cast<bool>(&a); 
    // Prints true
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << (p == nullptr) << std::endl;
```

This is how it looks when it's OK:

```
    int *q = boost::any_cast<int>(&a); 
    // Prints false
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << (q == nullptr) << std::endl;
```

This throws, because it doesn't take a pointer:

```
    try {
        boost::any_cast<bool>(a);
    }
    catch(...) {
        std::cout << "caught" << std::endl;
    }
```

Same for a string stored type:

```
    a = std::string { "Boost" }; 
    p = boost::any_cast<bool>(&a); 
    // Prints true
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << (p == nullptr) << std::endl;
    try {
        boost::any_cast<bool>(a);
    }
    catch(...) {
        std::cout << "caught again" << std::endl;
    }
}
```